# Google Sheet find cell by URL parameter

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a database of elements, each element has its own QR Code. After reading the code I would like to be able to open the worksheet on a specific tab and jump to the appropriate cell (according to the element name). Calling a worksheet through a URL with the #gid parameter allows you to open a tab.... the "range" parameter allows you to jump to a specific cell.... and what if I want to search for an item by name? Something like: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fER4x1p.../edit#gid=82420100&search=element_name.... is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

> Google has not introduced this yet

But you can look into Google Script  (Googles SpreadSheets macros like) to achieve this.
Also a simpler approach will be to just filter the data, but this will change your requirement obviously. For example you can create a Filter with the name you are looking for and then you will get the URL.

> This is the [URL to a Sample of this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1x3YjdsDqNe9qN7bEahKKXyPigs3WA-8MyW2wkW1y8x0/edit#gid=0&fvid=1694717033), it should open the
>   Spreadsheet and filter the data when loaded. [This is the Icon to
>   look for to create the filters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EQaS.png)

[here is some documentation](https://www.google.com/script/start/) for you to get started on Google App Script, but I don't have a direct link to let you know how to catch the parameters for it to process them. What I can tell you is that this is a much more complicated approach than just a URL because it involves programmatic processing on the Spreadsheet side.

Comment: OK, I know that I can finally use the app script but if I'm redirected from the QR code reader I can only use the parameters passed through the URL.... how to pass any parameter to the sheet / app script?